# Как правильно добавить в BindingList? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, коллекции, binding

объясните пожалуйста, как добавить данные в методе Save()?
и как найти индекс в _programModelsList?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly string _path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\programDataList.json";
    private BindingList<ProgramModel> _programModelsList;

    private FileIOService _fileIOservice;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        _fileIOservice = new FileIOService(_path);
        try
        {
            _programModelsList = _fileIOservice.LoadDate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Close();
        };

        ProgramWatcher _programWatcher = new ProgramWatcher();
        Thread thread = new Thread(_programWatcher.Wather);
        thread.Start();

        _programWatcher.NotifyStart += Save;
        _programWatcher.NotifyStop += AddInSave;

        _programModelsList = new BindingList<ProgramModel>()
        {
            new ProgramModel()
            {
                Id = "rr",                                                             
                Name = "rr"
            }
        };
        dgTodoList.ItemsSource = _programModelsList;
        _programModelsList.ListChanged += _programModelsList_ListChanged;             
    }

    public void Save(string id)
    {
        var proc = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(id));
        _programModelsList = new BindingList<ProgramModel>()
        {
            new ProgramModel()
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = proc.ProcessName,
                TimeStart = proc.StartTime
            }
        };
        _programModelsList.ListChanged += _programModelsList_ListChanged;
    }

    public void AddInSave(string id)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        int index = _programModelsList.IndexOf(id);
        _programModelsList[index].TimeStop = time.ToLocalTime();
        _programModelsList[index].LongTime =
            time.ToLocalTime().Subtract(_programModelsList[index].
            TimeStart).ToString("h':'m':'s");
    }
```

Comment: `как добавить данные` - `_programModelsList.Add(new ProgramModel());`. `как найти индекс` - `_programModelsList.IndexOf(нужный объект);`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `public void Save(string id)   
        {  
            var proc = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(id));  
            _programModelsList.Add( new ProgramModel()  
                {  
                    Id = id,
                    Name = proc.ProcessName,
                    TimeStart = proc.StartTime
                }  
            );  
            _programModelsList.ListChanged += _programModelsList_ListChanged;  
        }`

Comment: оно так не работает

Comment: Вы код я так понимаю скопировали где то? Ибо вы вообще не хотите разбираться в том, как все это устроено. "Не работает" почему? Наверно потому, что у вас NullReferenceExeption, так? А почему такое происходит? Потому, что объекты в C# надо инициализировать перед тем, как с ними работать. Также зачем вы постоянно при сохранение делаете подпись на событие?

Comment: ошибок не показывает, я не могу понять почему не работает(что не так написал). просто данные не появляются в таблице

Comment: В какой таблице? Вы объясните нормальным языком что не так в вашем коде. Не заставляйте пожалуйста нас гадать.

Comment: `_programModelsList = new BindingList<ProgramModel>()  
{  
new ProgramModel()  
{  
Id = "rr", 
Name = "rr"  
}  
};`

Comment: у меня есть таблица datagrid MainWindow.xaml, там должна отображаться коллекция BindingList<ProgramModel> _programModelsList.  То что написал выше в таблице есть.

Comment: В методе save создаётся новый элемент, а в addinsave должно найти элемент где Id =id, и добавить туда дополнительные данные

Comment: Когда вы пишете `dgTodoList.ItemsSource = _programModelsList;` - вы задаете указанный объект, как источник данных. Если вы где то напишете повторно `_programModelsList = new BindingList<ProgramModel>()...` - вы создаете **новый** объект, который не как не связан с ранее созданным. Инициализируйте коллекцию только один раз и дальше просто с ней работайте, вот и все.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать